# Which TeX primitives can be recovered after their initial definitions are overwritten?

Tags: primitives

This is mostly an academic question out of curiosity, but I think it may give some interesting answers. The question is, given a TeX file beginning with `\def\someprimitive{}`, for which values of `\someprimitive` is it possible to recover its primitive meaning afterwards?

For example, `\def\relax{}` is not catastrophic because `\csname` can be used to get at the primitive meaning:

```
\def\relax{}
\expandafter\let\expandafter\relax\csname PleaseGiveMeBackRelax\endcsname
\meaning\relax
```

Relaxing (no pun intended) the requirements a bit, one could ask if it is possible to recreate a macro which for all practical purposes does the same as the original:

```
\def\gdef{}
\def\gdef{\global\def}
```

(at least, I can't think of a situation where this doesn't work, but of course it depends on `\global` and `\def` not being redefined later on).

The question can be interpreted with respect to your favorite TeX engine and associated set of primitives. But relying on a format which creates an alias for a primitive is probably cheating (such as plain TeX's `\endgraf = \par`).

Comment: Your new `\gdef` definition would break in e.g. `\edef\foo{\noexpand\expandafter\gdef}`, because it is now fragile. You should use at least use `\protected\def\gdef{\global\def}`. I'm aware that it is just an example.

Comment: If you use amsmath they store quite a bit of the primitives

Comment: Of course, if you are prepared to cheat then you can save _all_ of the primitives, as `expl3` does (well, not all of the XeTeX and LuaTeX ones just yet, but close enough).

Comment: @Joseph: I put in the note about cheating precisely because I recalled that `expl3` did that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Besides `\pdfprimitive`, in Luatex you can map sets of primitives onto csnames by adding prefixes.  So for instance, `\directlua{tex.enableprimitives('Knuths', tex.extraprimitives('tex'))}` will map all Knuth's Tex primitives onto their basename with the prefix `Knuths`, so `\Knuthsdef` has the same meaning as the `\def` primitive.

The second argument to `tex.enableprimitives` is a table, so arbitrary sets of primitives can be mapped in this way.  `tex.extraprimitives` defines a table of primitives for the base Tex primitives and for each of the various extensions of Tex ('etex', 'pdftex', 'omega', etc.) supported by Luatex.

Answer (score 12):

With a current pdftex (luatex) you can retrieve primitives with `\pdfprimitive`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

{\def\hbox{I was a hbox}
 new: \hbox{}

 old: \pdfprimitive\hbox{abc}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\expandafter\let\expandafter\hbox\pdfprimitive\hbox` redefines `\hbox` back to its original meaning?

Comment: Ok, doesn't look like it.

Comment: @Martin: It looks like that would require something like Common Lisp's semantics of symbols for csnames: `\pdfprimitive\whatever` needs to expand to a csname different from anything Tex has seen so far, like an uninterned symbol.

Comment: @Charles: There should be some `\pdfprimitivelet` command then ;-)